# Should the interface define implementation specific enum values?

Tags: java, c#, oop, interface

Consider the following organization of classes:

```
interface Restaurant 
{
    public void dine(Object dish);
}

class ItalianRestaurant implements Restaurant
{
    public void dine(Object dish)
    {
        // eat with spoon and forks
    }
}

class ChineseRestaurant implements Restaurant
{
    public void dine(Object dish)
    {
        // eat with chopsticks
    }
}
```

Since both the restaurants serve completely different sets of dishes, what will be the correct way (design-wise) to represent the `type` of `dish` in the interface?

Will it be a good design decision to define an Enum listing all the dishes -- Italian and Chinese -- as a part of the interface, and use that Enum as `type` for `dish`?

Comment: Why not an interface or abstract class `Dish`?

Comment: It shouldn't be an enum at all. If a Thai restaurant currently serves Green Curry and Red Curry, and then want to add Yellow Curry as a new dish, do you truly want the restaurant to contact the developer to ask for Yellow Curry to be added to the enum? No! Restaurants should be able to define new dishes without requiring a code change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've used `Object` type for a Dish. Meaning anything can be considered as a Dish here.

Does that mean you can serve a `Phone` or `Pen` as a Dish? No; A dish is a dish. Why not create an abstraction for Dish as well?

Better design would be :

```
interface Restaurant 
{
    void dine(Dish dish);
}
```

`Dish` could be an interface or an abstract class; Choose one which is more appropriate. Then every kind of dish served will go as a separate class which inherits/implements `Dish`.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most correct way would be defining a generic interface like

```
interface Restaurant<T> {

    public void dine(T dish);

}
```

EDIT: well, I'm thinking in c#.... don't know if it suits